# Parcel Bundler: import scss files from node_modules without specifying the full path?

Tags: parceljs

Currently, I import scss files like this:

```
@import './node_modules/bulma/bulma';
```

However, in Laravel Mix I learned that I could just import the files like this, without specifying `./node_modules`:

```
@import '~bulma/bulma';
```

Anyway I could do this in ParcelJS?

Answer (score 5):

The sass-loader in webpack uses node-sass' custom importer feature to pass all queries to the webpack resolving engine.

But In parcel-bundler,

The node_modules resolution algorithm isn't implemented yet for SASS/SCSS. Currently you could make a .sassrc or .sassrc.js file to configure the node-sass includePaths option to include node_modules.

current workaround is found [in this discussion](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/39#issuecomment-353722786)